# Subclassing Modules in Node.js & JavaScript (without helper utilities)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to grok some alternate ways that I might go about 'subclassing' Node's `EventEmitter`

This is what I have working so far using es6/2015 style prototypical inheritance. It works well and is pretty readable (IMO).

```
class Emitter extends EventEmitter {
  // Hoping to augment #on() to accept a scope argument
  on(evt, cb, thisArg) {
    thisArg = thisArg ? thisArg : this;
    // This is the area I'm having trouble replicating w/ ES5
    return super.on.call(thisArg, evt, cb);
  } 
}

module.exports = Emitter;
```

I'm hoping to come up with a few other ways of how I might go about subclassing or extending EventEmitter apart from using the new ES6 way of doing things so I might better understand the underlying mechanisms at play. I'm used to using `Object.create(proto)` to set up the prototype chain, but I'm having trouble overriding the .on() method without causing a stack overflow.

I'm hoping to use the `thisArg` to let users set a context for the callback.

Here's what I have so far using an ES5 approach:

```
let Emitter = Object.create(EventEmitter);

Emitter.on = function on(evt, cb, thisArg) {
  thisArg = thisArg ? thisArg : this;
  return this.on.call(thisArg, evt, cb);
};

module.exports = Emitter;
```

Any ideas? I know you can use `utils.inherits()`, but would really prefer to figure out how to accomplish this without any 'magic' or helper tools.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do with this `thisArg`. Do you want to provide a context for the callback? Then use `cb.bind(thisArg)` instead of messing with the `this` value of the `on()` call.

Comment: Why do you export a `new Emitter` instance instead of the class itself?

Comment: Good point — I suppose I don't need to export a new instance of it. As for the `thisArg`, I'm hoping to extend .on() so that it can take a third argument and use it as a context. So, `.on(evt, cb)` => `.on(evt, cb, thisArg)`. I guess the broader question is something like "How do I properly subclass/extend event emitter in an ES5 way?"

Comment: Use it as a context for *what*?

Comment: Sorry, for the callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's fix your ES6 code. For what you want to achieve, you should use

```
return super.on(evt, cb.bind(thisArg));
```

instead of invoking `call` on the `on` method.

---

In ES5, you'd write this inheritance using the standard approach:

```
function Emitter() {
  EventEmitter.apply(this, arguments);
}

// these two lines could be `utils.inherit(Emitter, EventEmitter);`
Emitter.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype);
Emitter.prototype.constructor = Emitter;

Emitter.prototype.on = function(evt, cb, thisArg) {
  thisArg = thisArg ? thisArg : this;
  return EventEmitter.prototype.on.call(this, evt, cb.bind(thisArg));
};

module.exports = Emitter;
```

For the part you had trouble with, it's all about resolving the `super` reference by hand to access the parent's method that you want to call.

Comment: Awesome — thanks very much! Just so I'm positive I understand: we're calling the 'parent'/linked object's (since it's prototypal and not really parent/child classical) `.on()` method and supplying it with a this-bound callback. This is pretty much what `super()` will do. No? Thank you so much for your help & insight — much appreciated!

Comment: Also: could you clarify one more thing? I've seen the `EventEmitter.apply(this, args)` pattern a few times — is it just calling the EventEmitter constructor function within the Emitter or..? Just not sure how it functions in tandem with Object.create()

Comment: "*we're calling the 'parent' object's `.on()` method and supplying it with a this-bound callback. This is pretty much what super() will do*" - No, the this-bound callback (`cb.bind(…)`) has nothing to do with `super` and is just the business code for your specific use case. `super.on()` will do (parent).on.call(this)`, resolving the parent reference and call its method on the current instance.

Comment: Ah that makes sense — bungled the way I wrote it out, but I gotcha. Thanks again!

Comment: "*is `EventEmitter.apply(this, args)` just calling the EventEmitter constructor*" - yes, it calls the parent constructor on the child instance, to let it do all its necessary initialisation. It's like `super()` for the constructor, but also passes up all arguments.